# WordPress - www.####.com/?p=id

Tags: html, wordpress, url

I have a WordPress website however inside the "static" files .php pages they have used the php /?p=id so changing any permalinks won't take effect to this in WordPress.

Is there some sort of JavaScript I can write without having to manually change every url

I'm looking to change the ?=id to the complete url

Comment: This isn't a coding question. You might be better off asking at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Okay, that's now added.

Comment: You're 100% looking at permalinks with a structure like `site.com/?p=id`.  You're lacking an understanding of what you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to settings >> Permalinks and change them to your taste in there.

Please be aware that you may have to do additional server configuration if you have a nginx server

Comment: This will only change the links inside of a WordPress page and not static .php page links